# C++ conversion const pass-by-reference

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, conversion-operator

Given a template pass-by-reference conversion/type-cast operator (without const) is possible:

```
class TestA
{
    public:

        //Needs to be a const return
        template<typename TemplateItem>
        operator TemplateItem&() const {TemplateItem A; A = 10; return A;}
};

int main()
{
    TestA A;
    {
        int N;
        N = A;
        printf("%d!\n",N);
    }
    {
        float N;
        N = A;
        printf("%f!\n",N);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And given the following code (with const):

```
class TestA
{
    public:

        //Produces error
        template<typename TemplateItem>
        operator const TemplateItem&() const {TemplateItem A; A = 10; return A;}
};
```

Produces these errors:

> error: cannot convert 'TestA' to 'int' in assignment
>   error: cannot convert 'TestA' to 'float' in assignment

**Question**

How do I make it so the conversion/type-cast operator return a const pass-by-reference of the template type?

**Context**

Before most people come in and freak about how 'you can't convert it to just anything', you'll need context. The above code is pseudo code - I'm only interested on const reference returns being possible, not the pitfalls of a templated conversion function. But if you're wondering what it's for, it's relatively simple:

TemplateClass -> Conversion (turned into byte data) -> File
TemplateClass <- Conversion (changed back from byte data) <- File

The user is expected to know what they are getting out, or it's expected to be automated (I.E. saving/loading states). And yes, there is a universal method for templates using pointers to convert any type into byte data.

And don't give me claptrap about std doing this sort of thing already. The conversion process is part of a more complicated class library setup.

I'm a programmer. Trust me. C++ trusts me and lets me make mistakes. Only way I'll learn.

Comment: @Als: You mean, like that conversion method... in the class, right there?

Comment: As a general advice: You should not return references to temporary values. Return a value instead: `operator TheType() const {...}`, otherwise, you might produce a dangling reference.

Comment: @Als he already does it with conversion functions. I think what you meant to say was "Do **not** use conversion functions to do so."

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Ah, thanks for correcting that typo. I am going to delete that.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#260 , http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#976

Comment: @Johannes: First document is interesting, but it'll be template, so it will take on the type supplied (IE it'll have to be an int or float or whatever class as it'll have no choice). Second document on the template might be ill-formed but behind the scenes it will be using adaptation to the specific type. It's basically loading binary data from file and converting it to the template type. If the user gets out the wrong type, it's their own fault.

Comment: @SS first sentence is wrong. I recommend reading the C++ spec. I have no idea what the other statements of yours mean.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your conversion operator is already undefined behavior because you return a reference (const or not) to a local variable that has gone out of scope. It should work fine if you change your conversion operator to return by value which won't induce UB.

EDIT: (removed incorrect information about conversion operators).

But are you really sure that you really want your class type to be convertible to anything? That seems like it's just going to cause many headaches in the future when you're maintaining the code and it converts to an unexpected type automatically.

Another possible implementation is to create an `as` template method that basically does what your conversion operator wants to do and call it like `obj.as<int>()`.

Comment: Your first sentence is absolutely right.  The rest of your answer... well, conversion operators are the one place C++ allows overloading based on the result type (note that the result type is not, strictly speaking, overloading based on return type -- it's part of the operator's name)

Comment: I thought it was guarenteed that temporaries won't be destroyed until the operation in which they are used (I.E. the assignment) goes out of scope. If it works for a pass-by-copy (and the template class will not be dealing with small ints and floats - we're talking monsters like const char arrays and large classes for graphics), it should work for pass by reference, given the temporary, whether pass-by-copy or reference, won't go out of scope until the assignment is complete. Surely?

Comment: "But are you really sure"... I am absolutely positive. Trust me as a programmer, I am aware of the pitfalls in normal circumstances, but I am using low-level binary data conversion, loading classes from memory IE files, so it can work for any type - but the user is expected to know what is stored in the file (or it's expected to be automated for them). But this doesn't answer my question on a template const reference.

Comment: @SSight3: there are no temporaries here; just an automatic variable that goes out of scope when the function returns. Accessing the returned reference gives undefined behaviour. You should instead return by value and either trust your compiler to elide the copy, or in C++11 make sure that your large types are movable.